# How to store mongo db backups to google drive using Symfony 3.4

Tags: mongodb, symfony-3.4

I am trying to upload mongo db backup to google drive
I am installing following bundles [dizda/cloud-backup-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/dizda/cloud-backup-bundle) and [Happyr
/
GoogleSiteAuthenticatorBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/happyr/google-site-authenticator-bundle) for adapters I am using [cache/adapter-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/cache/adapter-bundle)

configuration:

```
dizda_cloud_backup:
output_file_prefix: '%dizda_hostname%'
timeout: 300
processor:
    type: zip # Required: tar|zip|7z
    options:
        compression_ratio: 6
        password: '%dizda_compressed_password%'
cloud_storages:
    google_drive:
      token_name: 'AIzaSyA4AE21Y-YqneV5f9POG7MPx4TF1LGmuO8' # Required
      remote_path: ~ # Not required, default "/", but you can use path like "/Accounts/backups/"
databases:
    mongodb:
        all_databases: false # Only required when no database is set
        database: '%database_name%'
        db_host: '%mongodb_backup_host%'
        db_port: '%mongodb_port%'
        db_user: '%mongodb_user%'
        db_password: '%mongodb_password%'

cache_adapter:
  providers:
   my_redis:
     factory: 'cache.factory.redis'

happyr_google_site_authenticator:
  cache_service: 'cache.provider.my_redis'
  tokens:
    google_drive:
      client_id: '85418079755-28ncgsoo91p69bum6ulpt0mipfdocb07.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      client_secret: 'qj0ipdwryCNpfbJQbd-mU2Mu'
      redirect_url: 'http://localhost:8000/googledrive/'
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

when I use `factory: 'cache.factory.mongodb'` getting

```
You have requested a non-existent service "cache.factory.mongodb" this while running server and while running backup command getting

Something went terribly wrong. We could not create a backup. Read your log files to see what caused this error
```

I verified logs getting `Command "--env=prod dizda:backup:start" exited with code "1" {"command":"--env=prod dizda:backup:start","code":1} []`

I am not sure which adapter needs to use and what's going on here.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance